# Why are young girls writing love letters to the Parkland shooter?

Tags: cognitive-modeling, decision-making, love, attraction

Nikolas Cruz, now widely known as the shooter responsible for killing 17 students in Parkland, Florida and injuring another 17, is according to both [CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2018/03/29/us/nikolas-cruz-prison-fan-mail-trnd/index.html) and the [Sun Sentinel](http://www.sun-sentinel.com/local/broward/parkland/florida-school-shooting/fl-reg-nikolas-cruz-prison-love-letters-20180327-story.html) receiving piles of love letters from young girls around the country.

What psychological phenomena would explain this?